# Why do I get `Could not find 'bundler' (1.17.3)` after upgrading Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bundler

After upgrading from Ruby 2.3 to a newer version and then doing a `bundle install` I get the error `Could not find 'bundler'`.

This happens even after doing `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because `gem install bundler` will install the newer 2.x version of bundler and the `Gemfile.lock` specifies the version of bundler to use at the bottom.

You can either:

### Install bundler 1.x

```
gem install bundler:1.17.3
```

If this does not work try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and doing `bundle install`.

### Upgrade Gemfile.lock to use 2.x

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Comment: Deleting `Gemfile.lock` is discouraged as a general rule of thumb so as not to cause dependency hell. Isn't there any way to avoid this and upgrade only `bundler`?

Comment: Did you try without deleting Gemfile.lock, it should work.

Comment: Yeah, no issues with your answer, finally got it to work. Just wanted to clarify that deleting `Gemfile.lock` should not be the first option because it could introduce another issues (ie. loosing reference of current gem's versions installed). I think it's an important disclaimer 